# Python function variable not working?

Tags: python

Here is my code

```
def gogogo (name)
    echo = "Hi there, " + name
    print echo

gogogo ("Gabriel")
```

It say that there is an error on line one but I can't find the problem, can anyone point out the problem? thanks!

Comment: You are missing : (colon) after gogogo(name)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `:` at the end of the function definition line.

```
def gogogo(name):
    echo = "Hi there, " + name
    print echo

gogogo("Gabriel")
```

In the future, please post the error you are getting as it really helps finding the problem.